# Discord.js V12 Mute role issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I want to be mute command for my Discord bit. I wrote some code, start the bot. There isn't any error, there isn't any message, it doesn't add any roles.

There is my code :

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const botconfig = require("../ayarlar.json");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    if (!message.member.hasPermission(['ADMINISTRATOR'])) return;
    let member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]) || message.guild.members.cache.find(x => x.user.username === args.slice(0).join(" ") || x.user.username === args[0])
    if (member.hasPermission(['ADMINISTRATOR']) && !message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) return;

    let mutedRole = message.guild.roles.cache.get('815193169343283240');
    let verifiedRole = message.guild.roles.cache.get('815193260761808917');
    if (mutedRole) {
        member.roles.add(mutedRole);
        member.roles.remove(verifiedRole);
        message.channel.send("Kullanıcı cezalandırıldı.");
    }
}

module.exports.config = {
    name: "ceza",
    description: "",
    usage: "l!ceza",
    accessableby: "Members",
    aliases: []
}
```

Comment: are you sure that your `if` statements are correctly phrased? Who do you tag when you test the command?

Comment: i tag my other account

Comment: does that account have admin rights? I tested your code and it works just fine

Comment: nonono there is not any admin rights. Account don't have any permissions (btw sorry for my english)

Comment: ok, well try to remove this part `&& !message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')` you don't really need it because you already check for that in your first line. Also see if your `mutedRole` actually exists. Thats the other thing that might be wrong.

Comment: still don't doing anything :( I check roles, IDs and i delete  !message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR') this code

Comment: have you tried to `console.log()` the roles? Also try to put a `console.log("test")` inside the `if(mutedRole)` block to see if that part actually executes.

Comment: Sorry for late answer. I put ```console.log('test')``` inside the ```if (mutedRole)``` but bot don't send anything to console

Comment: That means that your if block doesn't get executed which means your `mutedRole` doesn't exist.

Comment: No. I have a mutedRole and it's ID is right.

Comment: then I have no idea why it's not working for you. It works for me.

Comment: I know, this code works for everyone but don't works for me..